# Http post request data not passed

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am trying a simple post method to insert into a database.Below is the code to point me out my mistake.

This is android code to send a post request.I don't have any idea whats wrong but the parameter that is needed to be insert is not passed and an empty string is being inserted in database.

**java**

```
 String add = "myName";
 BufferedReader reader = null;
 String text = "";
 Log.d("K2NK", "Connecting....");
 URL url;
 String response = "";
 try {
        url = new URL("http://10.13.210.114/myDatabase/insert.php");
        URLConnection conn =  url.openConnection();

        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

        wr.write(add);
        wr.flush();

        //get the server response
        reader = new BufferedReader((new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream())));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        //read server response
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            //append server response in string
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        text = sb.toString();
        Log.d("K2NK", text);

    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {

            if(reader!=null){
            reader.close();}
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
```

PHP script is as below to insert data into database

**PHP**

```
<?php

$name = ($_POST['name']);
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "","syncadapter");

if($con->connect_error){
   die("Connection failed: ".$con->connect_error);
 }

//sql to delete record
$sql="INSERT INTO table_student (name) values ('$name')";

if($con->query($sql)===TRUE){
        echo json_encode("insert successful: name:".$name);
 } else {
        echo json_encode("insert failed");
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string you passed should be:

```
String add = "name=myname";
```

It is trying to find a Post variable by name **name** which does not exist.